# python GIF save Syntax error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
import images2gif as i2g
import sys, os

def water(img, watermark):
    mark = Image.open(watermark)
    try:
        im = Image.open(img)
        if im.mode != 'RGBA':
            im = im.convert('RGBA')
        layer = Image.new('RGBA', im.size, (0,0,0,0))
        position = (im.size[0]-mark.size[0], im.size[1]-mark.size[1])
        layer.paste(mark, position)
        frames = i2g.readGif(im, False)
        frames_out = []
        for frame in frames:
            frames_out.append(Image.composite(layer, frame, layer)
            i2g.writeGif('out.gif',frames_out, duration=0.5, dither=0)
    except Exception, (msg):
        print msg

 def test():
    water(sys.argv[1], "water.png")       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

I'm trying to make an watermark on a gif image above.

Here is complete code but it gives an error:

```
i2g.writeGif('out.gif',frames_out, duration=0.5, dither=0)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: There's a missing closing parenthesis in `frames_out.append(Image.composite(layer, frame, layer)`.

Comment: @aran-feyThank you But still i have some errors i am just beginner for python if would be glad if you help pasting the codes Above..

Comment: Well, what other errors are you getting? One thing I can see is that `def test()` is indented even though it shouldn't be. Is there anything else?

Comment: yes,  i have corrected it but now this gives an error like this 
C:\Users\Sly\Downloads\Compressed\Watermark\code>wm3.py neo.gif
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Image found

Comment: You should post that as a new question, and include the complete error traceback and everything else that's necessary to figure out the problem. You might have to explain what your program is supposed to do before someone can fix the error properly.