# Python,PIL+Images2GIF coercing to Unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, animated-gif

I'm trying to watermark an animated image using python, but I have got an error message:
`coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Image found`

```
def water(img, watermark):
    mark = Image.open(watermark)
    try:
        im = Image.open(img)
        if im.mode != 'RGBA':
            im = im.convert('RGBA')
        layer = Image.new('RGBA', im.size, (0,0,0,0))
        position = (im.size[0]-mark.size[0], im.size[1]-mark.size[1])
        layer.paste(mark, position)
        frames = i2g.readGif(im, False)
        frames_out = []
        for frame in frames:
            frames_out.append(Image.composite(layer, frame, layer))
            writeGif('out.gif', frames_out, duration=0.5, dither=0)
    except Exception, (msg):
        print msg

def test():
    water(sys.argv[1], "water.png")
```

Files:
[This is image that i want to put my watermark - neo.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY1Og.gif)
[My watermark - water.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZzVO.png)
[error during executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p2Kg.png)

How can I fix that error? I'm not able to watermark on gif image.
Here is full code on [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49528356/python-gif-save-syntax-error)

Comment: Please take out the `except Exception` part so we can see the complete traceback. We need to know _where_ the exception comes from. (Alternatively, add `import traceback; traceback.print_exc()` in the `except` block.)

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but [why does a beginner want to learn Python 2 instead of 3](https://pythonclock.org/)?